# Does officer package support old format of PPT files (Window 97-2003)

Tags: r, officer

R Officer package is not able to read old PPT files of type Windows Presentation 97-2003. It gives below error.
simpleError in zip::unzip(zipfile = newfile, exdir = folder): zip error: `Cannot open zip file`C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeYD5pQ\file41fc3c39b6.ppt`for reading` in file `zip.c:238`>

below is the sample code

```
content <- read_pptx(fileName)
data <- pptx_summary(content)
```

The content object should return rpptx object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the officer package only support `*.docx` and `*.pptx` documents. See https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/ for more details